# Android setting ringtone hardcoding external directory

Tags: java, android

My app sets the ringtone using the MediaStore class. Everything works fine however I have a question regarding the default path for ringtones. The path I am writing the .mp3 to is external storage /sdcard/media/audio/ringtones... will I have to programatically check if each directory exists before committing to a save path or is this path universal and on all androids? I have tested my app on 3 devices and it worked each time, however could there be a situation where a device uses some other directory other than the one hardcoded (mentioned above)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the path is universal. However, if a rooted user decides to muck around with it, errors may ensue.